# Editing text on a spreadsheet within a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which allows me to select text from within a spreadsheet based upon the values of two combobox's.

The question is; how do make edits on the spreadsheet when they are made on the userform?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Set s = ActiveSheet ' use for active sheet
    'Set s = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' use for a specific sheet
    For row = 1 To s.Cells(s.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
      If s.Cells(row, "A").Value = ComboBox1.Value And _
          s.Cells(row, "B").Value = ComboBox2.Value Then
          TextBox1.Value = s.Cells(row, "C").Value
          TextBox2.Value = s.Cells(row, "D").Value
          TextBox3.Value = s.Cells(row, "E").Value
          TextBox4.Value = s.Cells(row, "F").Value
      End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Well what's the opposite process to `TextBox1.Value = s.Cells(row, "C").Value` ?  Fill the cell from the textbox vs. fill the textbox from the cell.  Your other logic remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "row" is a module-level variable (declared at the top of the module) this is what you need, assuming you have a button named CommandButton2 that you want to click to save the data:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  s.Cells(row, "C").Value = TextBox1.Value
  s.Cells(row, "D").Value = TextBox2.Value
  s.Cells(row, "E").Value = TextBox3.Value
  s.Cells(row, "F").Value = TextBox4.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not following with respect to how or where to set the "row" as a module-level variable - assume complete ignorance no my behalf!!!

Comment: This is a follow up to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71841581/userforms-to-edit-text-with-vba.  Take a look at my post on that question and you'll see what I mean by declaring row at the top of the module.  By declaring the variable at the top of the module, it can hold its value from when you read the values from the worksheet until you write them to the worksheet.

Comment: I had completely missed that - as I said, you are dealing with ignorance here! Thank you for your putting up with me.

Answer (score 1):

### Binding a Userform Control on a Range

You can use the `ControlSource` property of a control.
This binds it on a spreadsheet range. All changes on the userform control will be directly go into the bindet range.That will also work on opposite direction.

**How to Use**

Create an empty Userform.
Put two textbox controls in it (`TextBox1 and TextBox2`).
Set the `ControlSource` property on both to the Target Range.

Keep in mind that you assign a `string` to `ControlSource`. Therefore you can build its value during runtime.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Set the Target Range to bind the control to
    TextBox1.ControlSource = "Table1!" & "A1"
    TextBox2.ControlSource = "Table2!A1"
End Sub
```

**Questions use case**

Here is the code fitting into your questions example.
Put this into an empty userform

```
Option Explicit


'
'   Create an empty userbox with the following Controls
'
'   ComboBox1 as ComboBox
'   ComboBox2 as ComboBox
'
'   TextBox 1 as TextBox
'   TextBox 2 as TextBox
'   TextBox 3 as TextBox
'   TextBox 4 as TextBox



Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim lngTargetRow As Long
    lngTargetRow = FindTargetRow()
    Call SetTextBoxControlSources(lngTargetRow)
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Dim lngTargetRow As Long
    lngTargetRow = FindTargetRow()
    Call SetTextBoxControlSources(lngTargetRow)
End Sub

' Finds the Target Row regarding the values of both comboboxes
Private Function FindTargetRow()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    Set s = ActiveSheet
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim RetVal As Long: RetVal = -1
    For Row = 1 To s.Cells(s.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      If s.Cells(Row, "A").Value = ComboBox1.Value And _
          s.Cells(Row, "B").Value = ComboBox2.Value Then
          RetVal = Row
          Exit For
        End If
    Next
    FindTargetRow = RetVal
End Function


Private Function SetTextBoxControlSources(lngTargetRow As Long)
    If (lngTargetRow <= 0) Then
        ' No Match, No Binding
        TextBox1.ControlSource = ""
        TextBox2.ControlSource = ""
        TextBox3.ControlSource = ""
        TextBox4.ControlSource = ""
        TextBox1.Text = "No Match"
        TextBox2.Text = "No Match"
        TextBox3.Text = "No Match"
        TextBox4.Text = "No Match"
    Else
        ' Set the Target Range to bind the control to
        TextBox1.ControlSource = "Table1!C" & lngTargetRow
        TextBox2.ControlSource = "Table1!D" & lngTargetRow
        TextBox3.ControlSource = "Table1!E" & lngTargetRow
        TextBox4.ControlSource = "Table1!F" & lngTargetRow
    End If
End Function
```

### Assign the Textbox Value to a Ranges Value

If you want to go only into one direction, you can assign the userform `textbox.text` property to a targets `range.value`.

```
Activesheet.Range("a1").value = TextBox1.text
```

This is only going from the userform into the spreadsheet.Changes made on the Spreadsheet will not update back into the userforms textbox.

*Using the ControlSource Method descripted at the beginning of the answer keeps you away from coding own update methods, so it helps you to keep the code more readable.*